# How to resize the navbar header image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include an image as my navbar header as the code shows below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #000000;" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The icon appears but very small. How can I resize it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to reduce the `padding` of `navbar-brand`.

**See the following example (https://jsfiddle.net/m9acxw28/1/):**

```css
.navbar-brand {
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #000000;" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Hint:** Make sure the custom CSS is placed after the Bootstrap CSS!